# Why can't I query related nodes of a node via Cypher, where the relationship exists?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to query nodes via Cypher with a specific relationship type.

So there are two nodes A (ID 1) and B (ID 2).
I'm using the Cypher Console within the Administration GUI.

If I do this:
    rel:1

I get a result of two relationships (IDs 10 and 11) two the same node (ID 3) (I know that is bad but that's the data).
If I look into the relationships there is shown:
    Node 1  SimilarTo  Node 3
    Node 1  SimilarTo  Node 3

If I try this:

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[:SimilarTo]->b WHERE n.Name='A'
```

I get an empty result!?

So my question is, why do I get that empty result, although there exist two relationships which have the right start node and the right end nodes?

I do not understand it.

If you have any suggestions please let me know ;)

OK I make another example..

I do following query:

```
START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:*')
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->sim
WHERE artist.artistName! = 'Shining Fury' 
RETURN artist.artistName, x.artistName, sim.artistName
```

And get this result (is correct):

```
artist.artistName x.artistName sim.artistName
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Holy Cross"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Holy Cross"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Shining Fury"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Shining Fury"
```

If I do that:

```
START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:*')
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->y-[:SimilarTo]->sim
WHERE artist.artistName! = 'Shining Fury' 
RETURN artist.artistName, x.artistName, y.artistName, sim.artistName
```

I get this (incorrect):

```
artist.artistName x.artistName y.artistName   sim.artistName
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Holy Cross"    "Dragonsfire"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Holy Cross"    "Ruffians"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Holy Cross"    "Dragonsfire"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Holy Cross"    "Ruffians"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"    "Holy Cross"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"    "Nightqueen"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"    "Dragonsfire"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"    "Holy Cross"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"    "Nightqueen"
"Shining Fury"  "Dragonsfire"   "Lorenguard"    "Dragonsfire"
```

It is incorrect because I'm missing The artist "Shining Fury" under y.artistName, like I got it in the step before.
I can't find my mistake!

Another edit..

Query 1

```
START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:*')
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->sim
WHERE artist.artistName! = 'Shining Fury' 
RETURN ID(artist), ID(x), ID(sim)
```

result:

```
ID(artist) ID(x) ID(sim)
210292  209410  228580
210292  209410  228580
210292  209410  212568
210292  209410  212568
210292  209410  210292
210292  209410  210292
```

Query2:

```
START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:*')
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->y-[:SimilarTo]->sim
WHERE artist.artistName! = 'Shining Fury' 
RETURN ID(artist), ID(x), ID(y), ID(sim)
```

result:

```
ID(artist) ID(x) ID(y) ID(sim)
210292  209410  228580  209410
210292  209410  228580  202357
210292  209410  228580  209410
210292  209410  228580  202357
210292  209410  212568  228580
210292  209410  212568  202279
210292  209410  212568  209410
210292  209410  212568  228580
210292  209410  212568  202279
210292  209410  212568  209410
```

Comment: Are you sure the name of the relationship is written correctly?  Case matters.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I made another example which I practically use .. I'm trying to query over one relationship type over several steps. The first and second step is correct, but the third step show a incorrect value for me. There are two nodes which are present in the second step, but missing in the third step! how could this happen?

Comment: Can you share the output of these two queries by including the node ids of artist,x,y and sim?

Comment: Yes of course, I include them in the example ..

Comment: Freaky...can't seem to spot what it is either. Possible to share your db somehow?

Comment: Yes same to me, at the beginning I thought that there is a problem because of the multiple relationships.. but the other connections seems to work. A share is pretty hard, the DB is 1GB big, it consists of 650k nodes, ~1Mill relations and ~1Mill properties .. but if there is a way i would share, the data isn't confidential..

Comment: k that's large to share. You might want to post this on the neo4j group- someone there would be able to figure this out most likely. https://groups.google.com/group/neo4j

Comment: works here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/uybgoo

Comment: delete the logfiles and zip the db, that should bring it down quite a bit, you can also share a link privately with michael at Neotechnology.com

Comment: are you sure your direction is correct?

Comment: I thought i do specify the direction by using the arrow .. I mean the query with two steps shows a result which should be part of the query which makes three steps.. so the node(s) with ID 210292 should still be part of the result. Am I right?

Comment: You might run into a cypher assumption that doesn't assign the same node to two different identifiers during a pattern match. Useful to filter out first level matches that you don't want to have in the second level. You can try to break up your match clause into two and use `WITH` in between to separate them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood right but I tried following: START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:*')
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x
WITH x as level1
MATCH level1-[:SimilarTo]->y
WITH y as level2
MATCH level2-[:SimilarTo]->sim
WHERE artist.artistName! = 'Shining Fury' 
RETURN artist, level1, level2, sim                    .... but get an error that says "Unknown identifier artist" ..

Comment: What I originally wanted to do is something like this: START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:*') MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo*3]->simArtist WHERE artist.artistName='Shining Fury' RETURN artist.artistName, simArtist.artistName             ... but as I used this I realized that the result is incorrect.. I made the other queries (doing step by step) because I want to make an ouput of each step to find the mistake.

Comment: For me it seems that the start node (Shining Fury) is not added to the result set of any step (for what reason ever), although there is a connection from any node to the start node again (loop)!? Could that be?

Comment: Now I have compressed the DB and removed the logs .. as result I have an 55MB file.. Michael if you are still interested in a share, now it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see no problem in there:

`artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->sim`

gives you identifiers `artist` and `sim` where in some cases the artist=sim. whereas

`artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->y-[:SimilarTo]->sim`

gives you identifiers `artist, x, y, sim` where the `y<>artist` because it is folowed by `sim` -> i mean, if you will be given the same identifier as in the first case, than the cypher match would run into an infinite loop, i.e. `210292  209410  210292  209410` (i bet the "Shining Fury" has connection only to "DragonsFly" and thus there simply can't be another sim identifier other than again the "DragonsFly".

try to add 1 more identifier and you will also see the part of the first query, e.g.:

`artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->y-[:SimilarTo]->z-[:SimilarTo]->sim`

will give you imo `210292  209410  210292  209410  xxxxx`

i suggest to be 100% sure you get the same nodes under the identifiers, either divide the query into 2 separate parts (as suggested in the comments with WITH) or strictly define you don't want any cycle in the query:

```
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x-[:SimilarTo]->sim
WHERE artist.artistName! = 'Shining Fury' 
AND Id(artist)<>Id(sim)
```

in case you must go through the loops, then do the dividing into 2 parts query solution

Comment: Ok you are right.. the artist 'Shining Fury' has (only one) connection to another artist 'Dragonsfly'.. due to this the first level went well .. now 'Drogonsfly' has several connections including one to the start (Shining Fury), which are all correctly returned in the second level.. doing the third step, the node (Shining Fury) is not included any more (as you said, Cypher would run into an infinite loop).. but i do not understand why cypher would run into an infinite loop, because the max steps for the match are defined.

Comment: I understand that I in some cases would get a result which is like    210292 209410 210292 209410 aso. ...  and that would be ok, but I do not understand the "infinite loop"

Comment: Following Cypher query works and results also the 'loop(s)':    START artist=node:artists('artistMbid:2190dd22-afad-43ee-8728-0bc00621f5ee')
MATCH artist-[:SimilarTo]->x
WITH artist, x as level1
MATCH level1-[:SimilarTo]->y
WITH artist, level1, y as level2
MATCH level2-[:SimilarTo]->sim 
RETURN artist.artistName, level1.artistName, level2.artistName, sim.artistName

Comment: actually, the term infinite loop isn't much infinite and i can't explain it better, it is just that cypher shall never traverse a cycle 2 times. a-b is a cycle, a-b-a is a cycle "and a half" and a-b-a-b is 2x the same cycle. at this point a take back my statement of `210292 209410 210292 209410 xxxxx` - this is possible if and only if there are more edges between those nodes and not just one "SimilarTo"